# Filter Multidimensional Array With One Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a group of checkboxes on a page that, when clicked, create an array of values (allVals) that change as boxes are checked/unchecked (string output is also an option). I also have another multidimensional array (recordSet), which I would like to filter (in example below: recordSet[i][5]) based on the checked values (allVals), and then return a new multidimensional array with only the matching indexes and their values. In this case it would return only the first recordSet[0] because "cat" was included. Each time a check box is checked/unchecked, recordSet would be filtered again and the newly created multidimensional array would update.

I have looked into underscore.js, which I am also using on the page, but unsure as to how to construct the filter and loops. Any help is much appreciated to point me in the right direction - open for other suggestions to accomplish.

```
allVals = ["cat", "dog"] 
recordSet = 0: Array[6]
               0: "somevalue"
               1: "somevalue"
               2: "somevalue"
               3: "somevalue"
               4: "somevalue"
               5: "Cat;Monkey;Elephant;Rooster"
             length: 6

            1: Array[6]
               0: "somevalue"
               1: "somevalue"
               2: "somevalue"
               3: "somevalue"
               4: "somevalue"
               5: "Giraffe;Turtle;Rabbit;Snake"
             length: 6

function updateSubTopics() {
    var allVals = [];

    $('.subCheck').each(function() {
        if  (this.checked){
            allVals.push($(this).val());
        }

    });

$(function() {
    $('.subCheck').click(updateSubTopics);
        updateSubTopics();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're looking for something like the following. (This example is a proof-of-concept, there's *definitely* a more efficient way to compute this.)

```
var animals = ['cat', 'dog'];

var values = [
    ['chicken;cat;', 'foobar'], 
    ['pig;rat;', 'dog;lizard;']
];

_.flatten(_.map(animals, function (animal) {
    return _.flatten(_.map(values, function (value) {
        return _.flatten(_.reject(value, function (x) {
            return x.indexOf(animal) === -1;
        }));
    }));
}));

// ["chicken;cat;", "dog;lizard;"]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B64j2/)

Comment: This looks good, but I only need recordSet[i][5] queried, whereas this seems to query all values in the array. Also, the original multidimensional structure is not returned. I have no way to reference any of the other values I need within each array (those "somevalues" are important in the next steps. You mention a more efficient solution, and I'd love to hear your suggestions. Thanks!